# How to use environment variable in Emakefile

Tags: makefile, erlang

I want to use environment variable in Emakefile to specify including path. It look like:

`{"./*", [report, verbose, {i, "/home/%%USER%%"}, {outdir, "ebin"}] }.`

My OTP version and info: Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [64-bit halfword] [smp:32:32] [async-threads:0] [kernel-poll:false] 
I found the double percent method from http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-patches/2004-September/000106.html Unfortunately it didn't work. Syntax check of Emakefile was passed and OTP started to compile it, but it could not find the .hrl file. The logs were:

`Recompile: ./test
test.erl:3: can't find include file "test.hrl"`

The Emakefile syntax information on http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/make.html is so limited.

Does anyone know how to use environment variable in Emakefile? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got answer from Erlang support group that at present it is not possible to use environment variable in Emakefile. What a pity.